# nginx ffmpeg hls streaming filling up my hard drive

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, nginx-config

I am using nginx and ffmpeg on my windows 10 machine. Everything works ok, but my hard drive keep filling up .
These are my command lines

```
ffmpeg -i "http://192.168.1.2:9566/history/" -copytb 1 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s:1]overlay[v];[v]pp=fd,scale=720:-1[y]" -map [y] -map 0:1 -s 720x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 1800k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 3000k -c:v libx264 -strict 2 -profile:v "main" -preset superfast  -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -vsync 1 -async 1 -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 6 -segment_wrap 10 -hls_flags delete_segments "D:\media\hls\history.m3u"
```

The HLS segments goes to D:\media\hls
This drive D: is ok, it's not filling up.

But the C:\ partition is filling up all the time.

the ffmpeg.exe is executed from Folder:
**C:\Users\Stefki\Desktop\ffmpeg-latest-win64-static (1)\ffmpeg-latest-win64-static\bin**

VLC play link http://192.168.2.254/hls/history.m3u OK

Thank you to all, I hope any experienced dev can help me :)

This is my nginx config file

worker_processes  1;

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
         location /hls {
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root D:/media;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
            }
```

Comment: I've had a ton of issues with FFmpeg HLS on Windows, and path specification not working.  I wonder if you're running into the same bugs.